# How to make glob2rx not add "^" to beginning of regex?

Tags: r, regex, text

I am using [glob2rx](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/glob2rx.html) to convert user input into regular expressions to match text patterns.

If the user inputs *run** , I would like it to match *runs* as well as *running*.

glob2rx works very well in constructing the regex, but it always adds a *^* to the beginning of the regex, i.e. it will match only items at the beginning of the string. However, I would like to match tokens within the string as well. For instance, in the example below, it does not match *I am running*, only *running am I* as it returns the regex pattern *^run* - I would like it to create *run*.

```
regex = glob2rx("run*")

for (t in c("running am i", "i am running")) {
  print (grep(regex, t))
}
```

Is there an easy way to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: It's in the docs.  `trim.head=TRUE`. You'll probably need to make it `glob2rx("*run**", trim.head = TRUE)`.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the fact that `^` always appears in the beginning. You can thus remove it with `substr(regex, 2, nchar(regex)`.

Comment: @RichScriven - it doesn't work that simply however. `glob2rx("run*", trim.head=TRUE)` gives `"^run"` - however, `glob2rx("*run*", trim.head=TRUE)` gives `"run"`

Comment: I know.  Sometimes we have to read the entire doc. `"*run**"`

Comment: @RichScriven - reading documentation? Get outta here!

Comment: @RichScriven @thelatemail thanks for that! I read about `trim.head` but figured that would require the user to input the extra _*_ s which does not seem intuitive. But I'll try to just add the addiitonal _*_ to the user input.

Comment: @patrick - `glob2rx` is essentially just a bunch of replacements via `gsub` - you could probably just make your own version which destroys the line which adds `^` and `$`. Type `glob2rx` at the R console to see what I mean.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes that sounds like the cleanest solution actually - I'm just not that familiar with regexes and figured I'd probably miss some edge cases ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip off the initial `^` with `gsub`:

```
gsub("^\\^", "", glob2rx("run*"))
```

But `glob2rx` is designed for a specific kind of input (file path "globs"), so there may be other issues that pop up because the function is designed for that input.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense! Do you think another function would be better suited to this? Glob2rx was the only one I found in the R regex docs that seemed to make that kind of conversion easy.