# extract files using glob2rx list.files

Tags: r, wildcard, glob

I want to `list.files` that contain something AND something AND end in `.png`. I can do it in steps but feel it is easier than that if I use `glob2rx`. These are the files:

```
[1] "cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"       
[2] "cc_ww_05_Mar_2021_.png"       
[3] "pp_ui_03_Mar_2021_.png"                      
[4] "zz_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"                      
[5] "pp_ui_03_Mar_2021_.png"                     
[6] "cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png" 
[7] "cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.csv"
```

I want to extract files that contain `ww` and `date_needed <-  "03_Mar_2021"` and end in `.png`:

```
[1] "cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"
[4] "zz_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"                      
[6] "cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"
```

To remove the `^` I included `trim.head` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787821/how-to-make-glob2rx-not-add-to-beginning-of-regex):

```
glob2rx(paste0("*WW", "*", date_needed, "*.png"), trim.head = TRUE)
# [1] "WW.*03_Mar_2021.*\\.png$"
```

but it doesnt work:

```
pnglist <- list.files(path = "folder/",
             pattern = glob2rx(paste0("*ww", "*", date_needed, "*.png"), trim.head = TRUE),
             full.names = T)
pnglist  
# character(0)
```

What am I missing? Is `glob2rx` the cleanest option here?

thanks

Comment: useful `glob2rx` examples https://hackmd.io/@Chang/string-manipulation-in-R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glob in the question uses upper case WW but the file names use lower case ww.  Also you could check that the folder path is correct.  Using

- inputs in the Note at the end
- the glob in the question but changing WW to ww and simplifying a bit
- using TRUE instead of T since T could be a variable masking it
- removing arguments we don't need

we have:

```
glob <- paste0("*ww*", date_needed, "*.png")
list.files(path = folder, pattern = glob2rx(glob), full.names = TRUE)
## [1] "./cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png" "./cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"
## [3] "./zz_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"
```

Alternately, use `Sys.glob` which directly uses globs:

```
glob2 <- file.path(folder, paste0("*ww*", date_needed, "*.png"))
Sys.glob(glob2)
## [1] "./cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png" "./cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"
## [3] "./zz_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png"
```

### Note

The input used was:

```
filenames <- c( "cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png",
"cc_ww_05_Mar_2021_.png",
"pp_ui_03_Mar_2021_.png",                     
"zz_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png",                     
"pp_ui_03_Mar_2021_.png",                    
"cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png",
"cd_ww_03_Mar_2021_.csv")
for(f in filenames) cat(file = f)

folder <- "."
date_needed <-  "03_Mar_2021"
```

Comment: Have modified answer to use your glob but with a folder equal to current dir and ww instead of WW.  Seems to work using either glob2rx or Sys.glob.

Comment: I realised that the problem in my data was that I was putting `date_needed` and `ww` in different order before `.png` e.g. `glob2rx(paste0(date_needed, "*ww*",  "*.png"))`. Is there a simple way to modify the code so order didnt matter? Also your `glob2rx(glob)` returns `"^.*ww.*03_Mar_2021.*\\.png$"`, I thought the `^` meant that it had to start with `ww` but it doesnt seem to matter here (it picks up `cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png` which starts with `cc`)? thanks

Comment: You can use | to specify either of two alternatives.

Comment: can you explain how `^` in `"^.*ww.*03_Mar_2021.*\\.png$"` picked up `cc_ww_03_Mar_2021_.png` which starts with `cc`, I thought `trim.head = TRUE` was needed to remove `^`?

Comment: ^ matches the beginning of the string and then .* matches what follows until ww.